# Prism navigation usage from Xamarin Forms App.OnAppLinkRequestReceived

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I am building an app that makes use of some App links. In below example, I want to open a ResetPasswordPage when the user activates a link from an e-mail.

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/LoginPage");
}

protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri.Host.EndsWith("site.nl", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(@"/appname/resetpassword/"))
        {
            if (uri.Segments.Length == 4)
            {
                string resetCode = uri.Segments[3];

                NavigationParameters param = new();
                param.Add(NavConst.PasswordResetCode, resetCode);

                await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("ResetPasswordPage", param);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but not what I would expect (for both iOS and Android). I would expect that ResetPasswordPage would be added to the navigation stack that was set in OnInitialized, so that it would contain a back button in the navigation bar, bringing the user back to the login page in this case.

But instead, it looks like the navigation stack gets replaced. When ResetPasswordPage is shown, and the user clicks the hardware back button, the app is closed. However, i want it to go back to where the user was before.

Am I not understanding some navigation concepts well or might this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NavigationService is a rather unique service within Prism for Xamarin.Forms. It is constructed new for each page as navigation and the navigation stack is dependent on where you are navigating from.

For instance when you Navigate from the context of a MasterDetailPage / FlyoutPage, it understands that you aren't trying to push a modal on top of that page but instead you are starting from the context of Detail/Flyout. If the NavigationService continually updated the Page context then the navigation service injected into that MasterDetailPage/FlyoutPage's ViewModel would have no idea that it needed that page as the context to navigate from.

Your issue here ultimately is that you are Navigating from the context of the Application which has a NavigationService with no Page set. As a result even a relative Navigation will still have the effect of an absolute Navigation thus resetting the Application.MainPage since that NavigationService does not have the contextual understanding of another page.

Depending on your business requirements you have a few different options. One is to do an absolute Navigation that gives you navigation stack that you're looking for.

Optionally you may want to get the currently displayed page and update the NavigationService to understand it. In the App class you might add something like:

```cs
protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{
    if (NavigationService is IPageAware pa)
    {
        page.Page = PageUtilities.GetCurrentPage(MainPage);
    }

    if (someCondition)
    {
        // This will now navigate from relatively from the page
        // returned by GetCurrentPage.
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SomeRelativeUrl")
            .OnNavigationError(HandleNavigationError);
    }
}
```

Comment: That explains it Dan. I was able to get it working using your code sample. Thank you.